# Using Xamarin ZXing.Net.Mobile - scanner stretched = ISSUE

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am currently using the package `ZXing.Net.Mobile` for Xamarin Forms. 
I want content on the top of the screen and at the bottom of the screen and I want the scanner to be somewhere in the middle.

If I specify the height of the scanner, it stretches it making it ugly and not nice to have (because the scanner is meant to be used for full screen?).

I want to have some content on the top of the screen with a dynamic height, then I want the scanner with height `150-200`, then I want some content to be shown on the rest of the screen.

I was looking into `ZXingDefaultOverlay` but I could not get it to work as I wanted.

Anyone has an idea, example or an answer that can help me?

Comment: You can leverage a Grid layout and have three rows, then dedicating each of them a desired portion of screen, either height or width.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the sample code where I have used **Grid** 
for showing content on top and bottom of the screen and middle screen contains scanner.

```
public ZXingDefaultOverlay()
{

BindingContext = this;

            RowSpacing = 0;

            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

Children.Add(new BoxView
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                Opacity = 0.7,
            }, 0, 0);

            Children.Add(new BoxView
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                Opacity = 0.7,
            }, 0, 2);

StackLayout ImageLabelContainer = new StackLayout();

            Image imgBox = new Image();
            imgBox.Source = "scan_qr.png";
            imgBox.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
            imgBox.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            ImageLabelContainer.Children.Add(imgBox);

            Label lblSuccess = new Label();
            lblSuccess.Margin = new Thickness(0, 7, 0, 0);
            lblSuccess.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            lblSuccess.TextColor = Color.Green;
            lblSuccess.AutomationId = "zxingDefaultOverlay_BottomTextLabel";
            lblSuccess.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(BottomText)));
            ImageLabelContainer.Children.Add(lblSuccess);

            Children.Add(ImageLabelContainer, 0, 1);
}
```

Here you can set height of the rows as per your requirement.